# PHP if not null then

Tags: php

I have the following code but really instead of matching the strings, I really want to do if $line, 88, 30 is not null then `$status = "delivered";`

```
if (preg_match("/pod/i", $filename)) {
    if (substr($line, 88, 30) == 'SOMETHING') {
        $status = "delivered";
    } else {
        continue;
    }
} 
else {
    ...
}
```

Am I right in thinking that I should wrap the `substr()` with an `isset()` or should I be using `empty()` ? I think I'm getting confused which way round it should go?

`$line` is below I only want to change status to delivered if a name exists

> CUSTPOD1.003123797001868810003660228092015102800Mark
>   CUSTPOD1.003123797001867710003660128092015095700

Comment: !== null not working ?

Comment: @DrunkWolf I want it to be not null though?

Comment: Won't `substr($line, 88, 30)` always be a string? And if `$line` isn't long enough, this will throw an error I think...

Comment: @WillWright hence '!==' instead of '==='

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php for reference

Comment: @Jerodev you're right it return an (empty) string or false, could use '!=""'

Comment: @DrunkWolf !== null doesn't seem to have worked, it's set the status to delivered even though it's null

Comment: Please provide us some examples for the content of `$line`. This way we can understand what exactly you are trying to do...

Comment: @Jerodev I have edited my initial question with two lines

Comment: How can `substr` ever work, these strings are only 53 characters long...

Comment: @Jerodev this website has stripped out some of the spaces I know that if (substr($line, 0, 7) == 'CUSTPOD') { works

Comment: @RyanVincent they are fixed length fields yes

Comment: @WillWright please also look into using`mb_` mutlibyte substr such as `mb_substr(...)` and it's companions, as without it PHP has very poor mutlibyte support and in future if you're given the strings in a non-unicode character set then it will screw up your results trying to read them as unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work with the following code, by storing the string in a var first I was then able to trim it and then use !empty (not empty) to check for characters

```
if (preg_match("/pod/i", $filename)) {
$somevar = trim(substr($line, 88, 2));
if (!empty($somevar)) {
    $status = "delivered";
} else {
    continue;
}
} else {
```

Comment: `if (!empty(trim(substr($line, 88, 2)))) {` should also work